# Sequelize class method works fine but instance method is not working

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've defined a user model in Sequelize, and also defined a custom class method and an instance method for it. I'm calling these two methods in my login api (which works fine). The problem is that the class method works perfectly, but the instance method results an error, and I cannot recognize what is wrong with my code. PLEASE HELP.

This is my user model and its methods:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../db/db.config");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

User.prototype.testMethod = function () {
  console.log("THIS IS A TEST");
};

User.beforeCreate(async (user, options) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
  user.password = hashedPassword;
});

User.findByEmailAndPassword = async function (inputEmail, inputPassword) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: inputEmail } });

    if (user === null) {
      return null;
    }

    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(inputPassword, user.password);
    if (!passwordMatch) {
      return null;
    }

    return _.pick(user, "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("FIND BY EMAIL AND PASSWORD ERROR: ", error);
  }
};

module.exports = User;
```

And this is my login router:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user.model");

router.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByEmailAndPassword(
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );
    console.log("USER: ", user);

    await user.testMethod();

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        errorMessage: "Username and password combination is not correct!",
      });
    }

    return res.status(200).send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({ errorMessage: error });
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are returning the regular object (from lodash.pick) from `findByEmailAndPassword`. But you are defining your instance method on Sequelize instance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Emma. Would you please give a hint on how can I return a Sequelize instance instead of returning a regular object from `findByEmailAndPassword`? What I'm trying to do here is to avoid sending user password in my response body. Is it possible to do it in another way without having this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason that you get the issue is that `findByEmailAndPassword` is returning the regular object from `_.pick` and you are defining the instance method for `Sequelize` instance. This instance method can be callable on `Sequelize` instance and not on regular object.

However, your goal is

> What I'm trying to do here is to avoid sending user password in my response body.

`defaultScope` is great for this use case. It allows you to define some repetitive options on a model.

You can define your User model as

```
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  ...
}, {
  defaultScope: {
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['password']
    }
  }
});
```

Defining the `defaultScope` on the model, this will be applied to many `Sequelize` functions by default.

> Scopes apply to .find, .findAll, .count, .update, .increment and .destroy.

I also tested that it also applied to `.findByPk`, `.findOne`.

So, how to use...

Call regular Sequelize `findOne` function.

```
const user = User.findOne({ 
  where: {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  }
});
```

By default, since `defaultScope` is applied, this won't return `password` in response.

In some scenarios where you need to return the `password`, use `unscoped` to disable the `defaultScope`.

```
// This will return `password` in response.
User.unscoped().fineOne(...)
```

For reference: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html